# .NET Core Identity cookie cannot be verified by another .NET API using database-stored DataProtectionKeys

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-identity, ms-yarp

I have a .NET Core Identity API that is not the direct internet facing API.

The Yarp API is the one accessible from the Internet and I want to use the Identity cookie to know if user is logged in and if not redirect him to login page.

I stored in DB the Identity API DataProtection keys to be accessible by all Identity instances:

```
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

All works fine I can see the key in the `DataProtectionKey` table in the Identity DB.

Now I want in the Yarp API to have a middleware that check the Identity cookie `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` if it is present and if it is ok to know if otherwise I should challenge the request to redirect towards login in Identity (login path is allowed by the middleware).
In the Yarp api I configured the same line towards same db and the authentication with cookie:

```
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie();
```

In the middleware I attempted both the:

```
var authResult = await context.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

and the:

```
TicketDataFormat ticketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);
AuthenticationTicket ticket = ticketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookieContent); 
//I can see in the cookieContent the encrypted string
```

but none of them are successful.

Any idea what else I should do ?

Comment: The scheme for identity should be IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme(Identity.Application) instead of "Cookie"

Comment: I changed Yarp api: 
 `services.AddAuthentication(options =>
   {
       options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
       options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
   }).AddIdentityCookies();`
and the middleware to
` var authResult = await context.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);`
but still no success, now the authResult has content for the Failure: `{"Unprotect ticket failed"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed [RuikaiFeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18177989/ruikai-feng) suggestion was correct:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>    
{
 options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;        
 options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;    
}).AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
```

but there was also something else: the SetApplicationName that need to be the same value in both apis:

```
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>()
.SetApplicationName("SameApiName");
```

And now the httpContext will show the needed information directly:

```
context?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated
```